# Apache: get fresh copy of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, web-server

I am running apache2 on Ubuntu 10.x and have managed to fubar the file "default" in /etc/apache2/sites-available, this has messed up my virtual hosts setup. Is there a way to get a clean copy of "default".

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Then, use the apache2.2-common package from the archive to reinstall any missing config files (which includes that site file):

```
sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2.2-common*.deb
```